# Image's ActualHeight and ActualWidth properties are different from DecodePixelHeight/Width

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows phone 8 application , where I need to show some images. I took a image control (didn't specify dimension) and am passing a ImageUri (pointing to local storage) and in the converter am returning a BitmapImage with DecodePixelHeight/Width set to 300 each. Its working fine except in a Nokia Lumia 920 phone (I tested in Lumia 520, Lumia 820, HTC 8S and Lumia 920). When testing in the 920, in the image_loaded event the image is having ActualHeight/Width as 480 each even when the image source's DecodePixelheight/Width are showing as 300 each. Why is this happening? (The image in isolated storage also is having the dimensions as 300x300).

This is my converter code:

```
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

    image.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical;
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
    image.DecodePixelHeight = 300;
    image.DecodePixelWidth = 300;
    using (var stream = LoadFile(path.ToString()))
    {
         if (stream != null)
         {
             image.SetSource(stream);
         }
    }
    return image;
```

[image: screen shot taken in lumia 520]

[image: screen shot taken in lumia 920]

I cropped the same regions from both the original screen shots.

Comment: Use DecodePixelType.Physical if you don't want the image to be rescaled to better fit a high resolution screen like the Lumia 920 has.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because DecodePixelHeight/Width will only make the image being decoded to that size. The size that actually is presented depends on other variables (Width and Height).

The fact that the result is different in the Lumia 920 is because this device has a WXGA (768x1280) resolution, where all the other devices have WVGA resolution (480x800).

This causes the image to be rescaled to adapt to the width/height of the resolution of a WXGA phone.

I don't quite know what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but i guess you are assigning the image that returns from that function to some kind of control. My advice is that you give that control a fixed width and height and see how that works out.